# mod_rewrite and .htaccess may not be running...or I'm an idiot

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've seen about 100 different mod_rewrite and .htaccess problems that people were having, but so far I've yet to run across a fix for my issue.

I set up a new computer macbook pro running 10.8.2.  This isn't using MAMPP or anything like that, just the native install of Apache.  Everything seems fine and seems identical to my other machine, but as far as I can tell url rewriting is not happening.

I've checked that the rewrite module is loaded...and it is, I've added  Allow all and all that stuff to my various .conf files and nothing is working.  I've just lost perspective on what to even try next.

I don't know if it matters, but I've enabled VirtualHosts and the site I'm working on does indeed load if you put the /index.php/ in the URL.

I'll post any code anyone needs to see, just let me know what you need.

here is the .htaccess file (that works on the other machine)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

my virtual host

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

ServerRoot "/Users/admin/Sites/dir"

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot mysite/awareness-thing
   ServerName awareness.test.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: Here is a gist to my httpd.conf file: https://gist.github.com/JoeCianflone/f580f7dd75d7e10f05a0

Comment: Removed php5.4 tag since this issue is not related to php. The only thing I'm not sure about in the rules is whether you should start the RewriteCond match with a slash. I generally see matches like that written with %{REQUEST_URI} rather than `$1` and the `^(.*)$` generally includes the leading slash, so the RewriteCond might need to be `RewriteCond $1 !^/(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)`. Since the rule works on your other setup, though, that shouldn't be the case unless you've changed context from Directory to VirtualHost or something.

Comment: Thanks, for removing that, I started somewhere to mention that this was a CodeIgniter application, but I'm pretty sure that is irrelevant.  I tried your suggestion and that didn't make a difference, I'm still gettingn a 404

Comment: Is the other site you're working on using a top-level domain?

Comment: Usually, my "test" to see if .htaccess is working is I just type random characters and see if I get a 500 error. If you don't then it is not being processed.

Comment: @Ares that's normally my test too...the perplexing thing is that I wasn't getting a 500 I was getting a 404.  Finally figured it out, it was a combination of things. I'm going to post the answer in a moment.   kjetilh it was.  I think that was part of the problem.  I made a few changes and got the whole thing working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be two issues going on:

I changed my .htaccess file to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

and I changed my vhost.conf to this:

NameVirtualHost *:80

```
ServerRoot "/Users/admin/Sites/site"

<Directory "/Users/admin/Sites/site"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot 2403_awareness-campaign
    ServerName test.awareness-campaign.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Just a combo of issues that made this a large WTF moment for me.